# Environment variable in YAML file for Ceedling not evaluated

Tags: yaml, ceedling

I have a Ceedling project for which i want to setup ceedling paths which are not hardcoded.
For this I tried both ways -

```
:environment:
  - :CEEDLING: 
     - my_ceed/ceedling
```

and

```
:environment:
  - :CEEDLING: 
     - "#{ENV['CEEDLING_PATH']}"
```

and using it like

```
:which_ceedling: ../../../#{ENV['CEEDLING']}
```

However this is not evaluated as expected -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    3: from /usr/local/bin/ceedling:23:in `<main>'
    2: from /usr/local/bin/ceedling:23:in `load'
    1: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.29.1/bin/ceedling:316:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.29.1/bin/ceedling:316:in `load': cannot load such file -- #{ENV['CEEDLING']}/lib/ceedling.rb (LoadError)
```

What am i missing here or is it not possible to do this for ceedling paths itself?

Comment: I'd like to help with this, but I cannot reproduce locally. Is there a little more info you can give? Also what problem are you trying to solve? If you use the as gem option, the install location of ceedling won't matter so this shouldn't be a problem with as gem.

Comment: yes default paths works.I am trying to use a specific version which is in the CEEDLING PATH option.Seems like code-pair options are only evaluated for use once after ceedling itself has been invoked.